# Google Classroom user role through API

Tags: google-directory-api, google-apps-for-education, google-classroom

I am using Google classroom to integrate with my .Net web application. I am using Directory API to create new users in google.After creating new user through Directory API if i am login to classroom its asking for role(Teacher/Student).My doubt is how can i create a new user as a teacher or student through API.I don't want to give option to user to login as teacher or student,i want declare that user at the time of new user creation only.How can i achieve this,or any other API to give role through code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the API currently doesn't support the ability to set the teacher/student option. We are aware of the demand for this feature and tracking it internally.

Comment: was this functionality added?

Comment: No, I don't believe this is available yet.